# Windows SBS 2011 Clients Randomly Unable to Access .co.uk Domains

Tags: windows-sbs-2011, internet, dns-server

We are a small office with 10 client PCs and one Windows SBS 2011 server acting as Domain Controller and Internet gateway. At random times client computers cannot access Internet hosts in the `.co.uk` domain (we are based in UK). We never have problems with `.com` or other domains. This has been for happening for a few months now.

This issue persists until the server is rebooted or the DNS Server is restarted, but will come back later at a random time.

Can anyone suggest a permanent fix for this issue? I have a background in Linux so this was all the information I was able to provide but I can post further configuration details if told what is relevant to the issue.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to http://support2.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;968372, this can happen when DNS name resolution is achieved through root hints:

> When name resolution is provided by root hints, Windows Server 2008
>   DNS and Windows Server 2008 R2 DNS Servers may fail to resolve queries
>   for names in certain top-level domains. When this happens, the problem
>   will continue until the DNS Server cache is cleared or the DNS Server
>   service is restarted. The problem can be seen with domains like
>   .co.uk, .cn, and .br, but is not limited to these domains.

You have two solutions at your disposal:

1. Configure your DNS Server to use DNS Forwarders instead of root hints
2. Change the `MaxCacheTTL` registry value to 2 days or greater

Instructions (found in the linked MSKB article) for implementing solution #2 follow:

1. Start Registry Editor (`regedit.exe`)
2. Locate the registry key: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\DNS\Parameters`
3. On the **Edit** menu, click **New**, click **DWORD (32-bit)** Value, and then add the following value:

   ```
   Value: MaxCacheTTL
   Data Type: DWORD
   Data value: 0x2A300 (172800 seconds in decimal, or 2 days)
   ```
4. Click **OK**.
5. Quit Registry Editor.
6. Restart the DNS Server service.